# Mean of timedeltas when resampling in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_timedelta(['00:00:02','00:00:05','00:00:10','00:00:15','00:00:05']))
df.index = pd.to_datetime(['20/02/2017 12:42:10','20/02/2017 12:43:10','20/02/2017 12:45:10','20/02/2017 12:45:10','20/02/2017 12:45:10'])
df.columns = ['time']

df
Out[232]: 
                        time
2017-02-20 12:42:10  00:00:02
2017-02-20 12:43:10  00:00:05
2017-02-20 12:45:10  00:00:10
2017-02-20 12:45:10  00:00:15
2017-02-20 12:45:10  00:00:05
```

I amb trying to resample it, getting the average time for each min.
P.e it works when suming them doing:

```
df.resample('min').sum()
Out[245]: 
                        time
2017-02-20 12:42:00 00:00:02
2017-02-20 12:43:00 00:00:05
2017-02-20 12:44:00 00:00:00
2017-02-20 12:45:00 00:00:30
```

There is any way of making this work with mean?

Something like:

`df.resample('min').mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert timedeltas to [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) (floats), `resample` and use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html). Last convert [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) back:

```
df = pd.to_timedelta(df.time.dt.total_seconds().resample('min').mean().fillna(0), unit='s')
print (df)
2017-02-20 12:42:00   00:00:02
2017-02-20 12:43:00   00:00:05
2017-02-20 12:44:00   00:00:00
2017-02-20 12:45:00   00:00:10
Freq: T, Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Increase precision is possible by converting to `nanoseconds`:

```
print (pd.Series(df.time.values.astype(np.int64), index=df.index))
2017-02-20 12:42:10     2000000000
2017-02-20 12:43:10     5000000000
2017-02-20 12:45:10    10000000000
2017-02-20 12:45:10    15000000000
2017-02-20 12:45:10     5000000000
dtype: int64

df = pd.to_timedelta(pd.Series(df.time.values.astype(np.int64), index=df.index)
                                 .resample('min').mean().fillna(0))
print (df)
2017-02-20 12:42:00   00:00:02
2017-02-20 12:43:00   00:00:05
2017-02-20 12:44:00   00:00:00
2017-02-20 12:45:00   00:00:10
Freq: T, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Will wait a few minutes and mark it as a good answer.